# Что быстрее кэш-память процессора или его регистры?

Tags: процессор

Что быстрее кэш-память процессора или его регистры?

Comment: Регистры. Нутром чую, а доказать не могу.

Comment: Вопрос должен иметь цель. Если цель - вы хотите достичь максимального быстродействия - то вам прийдётся учитывать и наличие кеш (делать выравнивание памяти по границам 4-8-16 байт), и наличие регистров (максимально использовать память регистров). И в таком случае одно другое дополняет.

Comment: Что значит "быстрее"? Если речь идет о доступе то конечно же регистры быстрее